# How to upload a file and save in local using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, upload

I am trying to upload a file and save it to my local instance of Mongo DB using React.

How should I do this?

Comment: What's your backend? have you seen this https://medium.com/ecmastack/uploading-files-with-react-js-and-node-js-e7e6b707f4ef

Comment: Can you be more clear what you mean by 'save in my local'?